# Uibuttons inside a custom uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have 2 buttons inside my custom UITableViewCell, one to add x1 quantity of the item already chosen and the other to subtract x1. How can i set the IBAction for the buttons within the custom class to be able to modify elements within the entire page and modify values inside my View Controller class? What would be the best way to approach this?[image]

I have attached an image of my storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `cellForRow` function, add button listener in this way

```
cell.plusBtn.addTarget(self, action: "plusBtnClicked:", for: .touchUpInside)
cell.minusBtn.addTarget(self, action: "minusBtnClicked:", for: .touchUpInside)
```

Then receive the call by

```
func plusBtnClicked(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
  score += 1
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func minusBtnClicked(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
  score -= 1
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: the buttonClicked func do i just add that in my View Controller? No code is needed inside the custom UITableViewCell class?

Comment: @Blackroche Correct. That table view cell class is linking your outlet with the code so that you can access then in your table view datasource and delegate functions. Try it out and let me know if you encounter problems.

Comment: so in the cellForRow it would then be cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", for: .touchUpInside) no? As i cannot create an IBOutlet for the button inside my VC

Comment: One last thing before i go and apply it now, the buttonClicked func, i just create that in the VC? Is tableView.reloadData() the only thing needed inside there (apart from my own custom code of course) to get it working or should it be tableview.beginUpdates() and endUpdates()?

Comment: Yes put that function in your view controller. So the function just provide the entry when you click on the button. You need to handle the +1/-1 in this function and then update the table view. Say if your table view loads score from a local variable, then in this function you need to do +1/-1 for this variable and then call reloadData()

Comment: So I would not have 2 different functions? To be able to determine which button was tapped, and add each function to its button respectively? I.e. Cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: "addBtnClicked"...etc and have similar but minusBtnClicked instead?

Comment: thank you so much it has worked perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

One is to use the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter).  You can add whatever objects need the +1 / -1 alert as an observer to be alerted by updates to the quanitty that the table view cell knows.

Another is to programmatically add the action to the buttons with the VC as the target having its Selectors triggered, so the buttons aren't triggering an action on the TableViewCell, they're triggering an action directly on the objects that need to handle it, rather than those objects waiting for an indirect notification.

Comment: Which would be the better approach?

Comment: @Blackroche - definitely *not* using NSNotificationCenter